# Управление сетевыми подключениями telnet

Tags: windows, windows-7, telnet

Необходимо подключиться к удаленному компу через telnet и запустить на нем сетевое подключение. Как это сделать?

Comment: Не очень понятно, на удаленном компе в принципе настроена сеть и не хватает только возможности заходить на него телнетом? Тогда https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc732046%28v=ws.10%29.aspx . Или Вы имели в виду что сеть там вообще не настроена?

Comment: сеть на нем работает, нужно, чтобы через telnet можно было включать другое сетевое соединение

Comment: Так заходите и набирайте команды, как если бы работали в окошке cmd.

Answer (score 1):

```
rasdial имя_подключения  
 ↳ [имя_пользователя [{пароль | *}]] 
 ↳ [/domain:домен] 
 ↳ [/phone:номер_телефона] 
 ↳ [/callback:номер_для_ответного_вызова] 
 ↳ [/phonebook:путь_к_телефонной_книге] 
 ↳ [/prefixsuffix]
```